# Displaying error message in php email form

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a basic contact form that gets a persons name, email, and comments then emails it. All the fields are required and I have error checking for the inputs in my php file before it sends the email. But right now if there is an error with one of the inputs once submit is clicked it opens new page and displays the error message. How would I instead just show the error message below the input that was incorrect?

This is my php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "email@address.com";
    $email_subject = "Personal Website Contact Form";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
}

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

header("location:contact.html");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you ajax request to do so. You can send a post request to your php file like this [Ajax Post Request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
and handle the request in php. Return the request errors or success message

Full example : [Ajax Request with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)